# Draw custom shapes in OpenGLES with an array of coordinates

Tags: opengl-es

Right now, I'm having no problems adding polygons like triangles or squares, but the problem comes when I try to add something more complex.

This is what I use for a square:

```
GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        50, 50,
        150, 50,
        50, 150,
        150, 150
    };
    GLfloat squareTexture[] = {
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        1, 1
    };


    glColor4f( 1, 0, 0, 1 );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );


    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, squareVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, squareTexture
```

That works perfectly, but what about an arbitrary number of points?

Let say that I have, for example, an L shape, with these points:

```
0,0         10,0






            10,80                     100,80

0,100       10,100                    100,100
```

This is an L (try to see lines joining the coordinates)

My question is, given these 7 points (or 8, or 100), how can I draw the figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your list of coordinate points you need to generate both a triangulated mesh and a set of uv coordinates (if you really need them). Once it is triangulated you can draw with a `gldrawarrays`

Here are some resources that may help you:

Triangulation
http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dm/CODE/GEM/chapter.html

Another Question that may help with UV generation:
[Calculating planar UV coordinates for arbitrary meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960930/calculating-planar-uv-coordinates-for-arbitrary-meshes)

if you were using desktop OpenGL instead of OpenGL ES you could actually draw without triangulation using `GL_POLYGONS`...

Comment: Thank, what do you mean with I was on MAC? Im working on iOS (iPhone). Can I do it too?

Comment: No its not part of OpenGLES only OpenGL

Comment: And even then concave polygons aren't handled.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert the shape to a list of triangles.

Comment: The problem is that in my application, I only going to receive an array of points (coordinates), but the shape can be an L, or something even much more complex. Is there any algorithm to create that?